# How do I keep audio from IE playing when switching apps on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, pandora

I use Pandora.com to listen to music in IE on Windows 8.  When I switch to another app, the audio cuts out.  How can I keep it playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's a limitation of "metro" UI apps - assuming you're using MSIE in that mode.

If it's not the default browser, or you're using in "desktop" mode - maybe starting it from the desktop instead of the start screen - it should/may continue in the background.

Comment: This is correct.  If you're using the Metro version, when you tab away, the app is "frozen", thus anything "in browser" will be frozen also.  Try running from the desktop version of IE, or try to snap the Metro IE to the side instead of moving away from it entirely.  You can also find an app in the store and run Pandora that way, which should run in a background process and keep the music playing while you do other things.